# Select next adjacent element JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a group of file input fields and I want all to be disabled except for the first one.

When the first one is set (onchanged), the next file field is unlocked.

How do I do this? I have tried:

```
$('#topperform input').change(function(){

$(this).next('label').css('color', 'red') ;

})
```

Which does nothing.

My HTML:

```
<form id="topperform" method="post">
<label>Main image <input type="file" /></label>
<label>2nd image <input type="file" /></label>
<label>3rd image <input type="file" /></label>
<label>4th image <input type="file" /></label>
<label>5th image <input type="file" /></label>
<label>6th image <input type="file" /></label>
<label>7th image <input type="file" /></label>
<label>8th image <input type="file" /></label>
<label>9th image <input type="file" /></label>
<label>10th image <input type="file" /></label>
</form>
```

Comment: i might be mistaken but why did u put $('#topperform input') and not $('#topperform')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Check the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MVmr6/)***:

```
var inputs = $('#topperform').find('input');

inputs.not(':first').prop('disabled',true);

inputs.change(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().find('input').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().next('label').css('color', 'red');
```

`$(this)` is the input, you need the next sibling of the input's parent (The label).

**[Working sample](http://fiddle.jshell.net/N3R6v/)**

Comment: **$(this)** is referencing the input.

Answer (score 0):

use css-classes to check current state of your entry. when you just set the class of your label elements to "disabled" (for example ;)) you remove this class from your label after editing the input field. and enable the next field by selecting it with: $('.disabled')

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add ids to the inputs (`f1` for the first...`f10` for the last). After that you can use this script:

```
$('#topperform input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#topperform input').change(function () {
    var id = parseInt(this.id.replace(/^f/, ''), 10);
    $('#f' + (id + 1)).removeAttr('disabled');
});
$('#f1').removeAttr('disabled');
​
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/VpGbH/

In my opinion this makes the best balance between readability and performance.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form id="topperform" method="post">
<label>Main image <input type="file"/></label>
<label>2nd image <input type="file" disabled = "disabled" /></label>
<label>3rd image <input type="file" disabled = "disabled"  /></label>
<label>4th image <input type="file" disabled = "disabled" /></label>
<label>5th image <input type="file" disabled = "disabled" /></label>
<label>6th image <input type="file" disabled = "disabled" /></label>
<label>7th image <input type="file" disabled = "disabled" /></label>
<label>8th image <input type="file" disabled = "disabled" /></label>
<label>9th image <input type="file" disabled = "disabled" /></label>
<label>10th image <input type="file" disabled = "disabled" /></label>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Javascript

```
 $('#topperform').find('input').change(function() {
     $(this).parent().next().find('input').prop('disabled', false);
 });​
```